# SSRS Drop Down List Problems

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

This questions kind of carries on top of the previous question I asked. Anyhow, I am creating this report in Report Builder 3.0. I have about 5 tables, **1 - 5**. I have a drop down list that displays the table names **1-5**. However, I want to regroup some of the tables together. For instance, the upgraded drop down would look something like this:

Drop Down List:

**One&Two**

**Three&Four**

**Five**

So If i were to click on **One&Two**, tables **1 and 2** would display while the others would stay hidden.

```
((CASE WHEN 'All' = 'All' THEN 1 
   WHEN @Input = 'One&Two' THEN 1 
   When @Input = 'One&Two' THEN 2
      ELSE 0 END) = 1)
```

Using the above case doesn't do anything.

In my tablix properties I have the following command:

```
=Parameters!Input.Value <> "One&Two" AND Parameters!Input.Value <> "All"
```

This doesn't give me the table nor the columns, however doing this for a textbox it works. Going back to my original problem, how can I display 2 tables using only one drop down value from the list and hide the rest. I tried doing the multi select, but that didn't work out so well, because of the visibility issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the hidden property evidently. Can you check and make sure you should be using label to compare?

```
=Parameters!Input.Label<> "One&Two" AND Parameters!Input.Label<> "All"
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'One' to data type int.
----------------------------
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset SSRS.
----------------------------
An error has occurred during report processing.
----------------------------
An error occurred during local report processing.

Comment: The Parameter.Label is always a string. You must be using another value somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, fixed that problem. Now, I am only able to see the table rather then the values inside it.

Comment: You should not have to hide both the table and the text inside, just the table should work.

Comment: I am not hiding the Text that is inside. In the tablix properties, "Row Group Properties", visibility is set to "Show".